# malloc returns 0x100000000

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have a strange problem with `malloc`. After allocating <10mb with a number of mallocs, malloc suddenly returns the address `0x100000000`, which causes a SIGSEGV when accessed. I have no idea what is wrong. The `errno` is set to `0` and I have enough space in ram, so it shouldn't be a space problem. The last addresses returned by malloc were smaller than `0x6255f0`. Any idea what to look for?

Some info about my system:

- gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5)
- flags: -Wall
- uname: 2.6.35-27-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 22 20:25:46 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

PMAP output:

```
Address           Kbytes     RSS   Dirty Mode   Mapping
0000000000400000       0      32       0 r-x--  tests
000000000060a000       0       4       4 r----  tests
000000000060b000       0       4       4 rw---  tests
000000000060c000       0     116     116 rw---    [ anon ]
00007ffff75cd000       0     348       0 r-x--  libc-2.12.1.so
00007ffff7747000       0       0       0 -----  libc-2.12.1.so
00007ffff7946000       0      16      16 r----  libc-2.12.1.so
00007ffff794a000       0       4       4 rw---  libc-2.12.1.so
00007ffff794b000       0      12      12 rw---    [ anon ]
00007ffff7950000       0      32       0 r-x--  libm-2.12.1.so
00007ffff79d2000       0       0       0 -----  libm-2.12.1.so
00007ffff7bd1000       0       4       4 r----  libm-2.12.1.so
00007ffff7bd2000       0       4       4 rw---  libm-2.12.1.so
00007ffff7bd3000       0      28       0 r-x--  liblinopt.so
00007ffff7bdb000       0       0       0 -----  liblinopt.so
00007ffff7dda000       0       4       4 r----  liblinopt.so
00007ffff7ddb000       0       4       4 rw---  liblinopt.so
00007ffff7ddc000       0     108       4 r-x--  ld-2.12.1.so
00007ffff7f6c000       0     432     432 rw---    [ anon ]
00007ffff7ff8000       0      12      12 rw---    [ anon ]
00007ffff7ffb000       0       4       0 r-x--    [ anon ]
00007ffff7ffc000       0       4       4 r----  ld-2.12.1.so
00007ffff7ffd000       0       4       4 rw---  ld-2.12.1.so
00007ffff7ffe000       0       4       4 rw---    [ anon ]
00007ffffffde000       0      16      16 rw---    [ stack ]
ffffffffff600000       0       0       0 r-x--    [ anon ]
----------------  ------  ------  ------
total kB            9160    1196     648

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7bd8e67 in bound_knapsack (sizes=0x610b30, profits=0x610ad0, B=103, 
    limit=2) at /home/x/Development/binpacking/src/lib/knapsack.c:123
```

### UPDATE

Running valgrind revealed the problem: it was a calloc some lines before:
`calloc( n, sizeof(unsigned int));`
which should have been:
`calloc( n, sizeof(unsigned int*));`
which lead to a too small allocated block, which is used to store the result of the malloc.
*sigh*

Thank you for rubber ducking!

Comment: Can you post the code you are using? (as small a code snippet as demonstrates this, please.) Also, remember that "out of memory" != "not enough RAM," it means "out of address space" and that Linux overcommits memory by default, so address space allocations may succeed but accessing the allocation may fail on page-in (though if you have a lot of free memory, that's not likely to be a problem).

Comment: This could be due to some sort of memory corruption in another `malloc`ed block.  Have you tried running this through `valgrind`?

Comment: You might have a problem somewhere else, that is manifesting itself when you try to allocate more memory.

Comment: -1 because that "question" does not add anything to SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the following line to your program:

```
#define MALLOC_CHECK_ 3
```

This should cause a different version of `malloc` to be used, one that can detect certain errors and report them to you.  See the 'Notes' section of the [malloc man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` worked fine, but the result wasn't stored. ( see Update ).
Thank you for your suggestions.

If you still wan't to see some code:
[github/knapsack.c](https://github.com/hannesg/binpacking/blob/6fb72cc7f40c0ec4549017cdfd9eb3da36209276/src/lib/knapsack.c#L111)